# Spring-cloud-sleuth async methods

Tags: java, asynchronous, trace, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have to add @Async annotation to method so Sleuth could generate span id and trace id. The problem is that it i need the same trace id as from the call side, but it is another.

```
main log: INFO [label-service,**a3a1f1db46aecf7a**,**a3a1f1db46aecf7a**]
async log: INFO [label-service,**b819bd0e67ee86c4**,b819bd0e67ee86c4]
```

I need ids in ** to be the same.

Comment: Please provide any meaningful information like which version of sleuth, boot, cloud you're using? how are you making the call etc. Without this information there's no way to help you

Comment: boot version 2.5.6
sleuth version is 3.0.5
The call provides by : CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> methodName())

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak

Answer (score 0):

You will have to enable this behavior by setting the value of `spring.sleuth.async.enabled` to `true`.